# Use Word2Vec to build a sense embedding

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec, word-embedding

I really accept every hint on the following problem, because all what i want is to obtain that embedding from that dataset, I will write my all solution because (hopefully) the problem is just in some parts that i didn't consider.

I'm working with an annotated corpus, such that i have disambiguate words in a given sentence thanks to WordNet synsets id, that i will call tags. For example:

#### Dataset

```xml
<sentence>
  <text>word1 word2 word3</text>
  <annotations>
    <annotation anchor=word1 lemma=lemma1>tag1</annotation>
    <annotation anchor=word2 lemma=lemma2>tag2</annotation>
    <annotation anchor=word3 lemma=lemma3>tag3</annotation>
  <annotations>
</sentence>
```

Starting from this, given an embedding dimension that i will call n, i would like to build an embedding like this:

#### Embedding

```
lemma1_tag1 dim 1 dim 2 dim 3 ... dim n
lemma2_tag2 dim 1 dim 2 dim 3 ... dim n
lemma3_tag3 dim 1 dim 2 dim 3 ... dim n
```

I thought to generate a corpus for Word2Vec starting from each text of each sentence, and replace each `anchor` with the respective `lemma1_tag1` (some words can contain more underscore, because i replaced space in lemmas with underscores). Since not every single word is annotated, after a simple preprocessing performed to remove stopwords and other punctuation, in the end i have something like the following example:

#### Corpus Example

```
let just list most_recent_01730444a headline_06344461n
```

Since I'm just interested in annotated words, I also generated a predefined vocabulary to use it as Word2Vec vocabulary. This file contains on each row entries like:

#### Vocabulary Example

```
lemma1_tag1
lemma2_tag2
```

So, after having defined a corpus and a vocabulary, I used them in Word2Vec toolkit:

#### Terminal emulation

```
./word2vec -train data/test.txt -output data/embeddings.vec -size 300 -window 7 -sample 1e-3 -hs 1 -negative 0 -iter 10 -min-count 1 -read-vocab data/dictionary.txt -cbow 1
```

#### Output

```
Starting training using file data/test.txt
Vocab size: 80
Words in train file: 20811
```

The problem is that the number of words in the corpus is 32000000+ and the number of words in the predefined vocabulary file is about 80000. I even tried in Python with Gensim, but (of course) I had the very same output. I think that the problem is that Word2Vec doesn't consider words in the format `lemma1_tag1` because of the underscore, and i don't know how to solve this problem. Any hint is appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the original `word2vec.c` from Google, and gensim's `Word2Vec`, handle words with underscores just fine.

If both are looking at your input file, and both reporting just 80 unique words where you're expecting 100,000-plus, there's probably something wrong with your input-file.

What does `wc data/test.txt` report?

Comment: Performing wc on test.txt file, i get  `1920131  32639925 339425485 test.txt`. Performing it on dictionary.txt file, i get `79353   79353 1600812 dictionary.txt`. In the question i wrote 100000+ while there are only 79353 words in the dictionary, but that's fine, i will edit the question. The number of words in the test file is ok, 32milion+. This seems really strange

Comment: Why are you using the `-read-vocab` option, rather than just letting the vocabulary be discovered from the corpus? (I would suggest eliminating use of that less-common option as a factor. If there are words you're not interested in, you could just strip them from the corpus.)

Comment: I added that option because there are some context words that i'm not interested to report them in the embedding (i Just care about the words represented as `lemma_tag`), but they are usefull to compute the weights of the target words. Or at least, I understood that in w2v also out of vocabulary words affect the final embedding, that's why i left them and didn't strip them from the corpus.